# Run JavaScript after the page loads (document.ready)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following script inside my master page :-

```
<script type= "application/javascript">
document.getElementById("currentdate").innerHTML = EMBEDformatAMPM();
var myVar=setInterval(function(){myTimer()},30000);
function myTimer()
{
document.getElementById("currentdate").innerHTML = EMBEDformatAMPM();
}
//code goes here
}</script>
```

but the problem i am facing is that the script will run before the `(currentdate").innerHTML` loads, and the script will raise a null reference exception, so my question is basically about how i can force the javaScript to run after the page loads.?
Thanks

**EDIT**

My jQuery file is raising the following error ,, not sure why :-

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: visited
```

[image]

Comment: Are you asking for a non-jQuery solution?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Where exactly is this inline script placed in your master page? And what did you mean when you said:

"the script will run before the `("currentdate").innerHTML` loads?"

Are you referring to the rendering of the element?

Comment: this script is directly added to my master page ,, at the bottom

Comment: If your script is placed right before the closing `</body`, you don't need to register your code to any `onload` event.

Comment: Regarding that jQuery Error: The `:visited` pseudo selector isn't supported. (Don't ask me why). Use the jquery.visited plugin. http://remysharp.com/2008/02/25/visited-plugin

Answer (score 5):

For Non-jQuery Solution:

```
window.onload = function(){
    YOUR CODE HERE;
};
```

For jQuery Solution:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    CODE HERE;
});
```

Greetings

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728922/why-not-use-javascript-handlers-on-the-body-element

Comment: Just edited the comment...

Answer (score 2):

With jQuery, this is extremely simple:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Your code here.
});
```

There are several ways to do it without jQuery, though these are more complex.  Some of the best of them are available as answers to this question on StackOverflow: [$(document).ready equivalent without jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799981/document-ready-equivalent-without-jquery)

**Edit (to address question edit)**:
If you're using jQuery anyway, consider rewriting what you have above to something like the following:

```
<script type= "application/javascript">
$("#currentdate").html(EMBEDformatAMPM());
var myVar = setInterval(function(){myTimer()},30000);
function myTimer()
{
  $("#currentdate").html(EMBEDformatAMPM());
}
</script>
```

If this part needs to wait until the document is ready, then it should also have the code for that wrapped around it:

```
<script type= "application/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#currentdate").html(EMBEDformatAMPM());
  var myVar = setInterval(function(){myTimer()},30000);
  function myTimer()
  {
    $("#currentdate").html(EMBEDformatAMPM());
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: can you check my edit to the original question, as my jQuery 1.10.2 is raising errors?

Answer (score 0):

Since Jquery is one of your tags in your question, you can just use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //your code to run

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code *should* run well if you place your inline script right before the closing  tag, or after writing HTML for `#currentdate`. And please tell me if it doesn't.

The reason why that JavaScript error is being thrown is because the `:visited` pseudo selector is no longer supported. That feature allows websites to track users and has been removed for some privacy reasons.

You can read more about that [here](https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2010/03/31/plugging-the-css-history-leak/).

Don't worry, there's a workaround. You can use the [*visited* plugin by Remy Sharp](http://remysharp.com/2008/02/25/visited-plugin). If you're using `:visited` just for styling purposes, remove it, unless it's necessary.