# Textbox default text make disappear on focus

Tags: asp.net

```
TextBox t1 = new TextBox();
qwe2.controls.AddControl(t1);
```

I added textbox dynamically to qwe2 
qwe2 is just a panel

```
  <asp:panel ID="qwe2" runat="server"></asp:panel>
```

so how can i set default text to my text and when text box is focused i want it to disappear?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will set a default value, then remove it on focus. If the textbox is blank, it will add the default value back on blur.

```
TextBox t1 = new TextBox();
t1.Attributes.Add("value", "Default text...");
t1.Attributes.Add("onFocus",@"if(this.value == 'Default text...') {this.value = '';}");
t1.Attributes.Add("onBlur", @"if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Default text...';}");
qwe2.controls.AddControl(t1);
```

EDIT:
switching font color, though I would advise you to rather use the Jquery placeholder plugin instead https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder

```
t1.Attributes.Add("value", "Default text...");
t1.Style.Add("color", "LightGrey");
t1.Attributes.Add("onFocus", @"if(this.value == 'Default text...') {this.value = '';this.style.color ='LightGrey';}else{this.style.color = '';}");
t1.Attributes.Add("onBlur", @"if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Default text...';this.style.color ='LightGrey';}else{this.style.color = '';}");
t1.Attributes.Add("onClick", "this.style.color = '';");
```

Comment: Thanks it works))))) one more question the text looks like normal text  can i do it shadow greybydefault? you know there is special type of text in textboxes

Comment: It shouldn't do that, cos you're only clearing the value when its "Default text...".

Comment: Upd: i didn't noticed i didn't deleteold version  `tbox("sometext ", t1);`  it's working but on blur seems not to be working it lefts textbox empty upd2: fixed the problem it's my mistake ))

Answer (score 0):

Set default text of a textbox:

```
t1.Text = "Your default text here.";
```

For the focus event, you'll find the answer **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12526429/how-to-get-gotfocus-lostfocus-event-of-a-textbox-in-webforms-using-c-sharp)**. Hope this helps.

**Edit:**

The link I provided is an answer to handle the change of focus, not to set the focus. You can set the focus of a textbox using the `Focus()` method:

```
t1.Focus();
```

Comment: Sadly i can't use this link , because I need to set  on focus event in code behind so....

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add placeholder dynamically. you can do with..

```
t1.Attributes.Add("placeholder", "--your default text here--");
```

try it.

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
    t1.Attributes.Add("onfocus","if (this.value == 'Full Name') {this.value = '';}");
    t1.Attributes.Add("onblur","if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Full Name';}");
    qwe2.controls.AddControl(t1);
    t1.Focus();
```

I hope its may help...