# How to clear the text on the textbox once you click the textbox on VB.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm setting the default value of a textbox to 0, but I want to clear the default value(0) once the user click the textbox.

I've searched, I saw gotFocus() but the textbox on VB.Net doesn't have GotFocus(). Is there other way to do this? It doesn't have click event too.

Comment: Is this a web page?

Comment: It is a webpage.

Comment: You'll need to use JavaScript to do this. OnFocus would be the simplest way however if the user leaves the text box and goes back you could clear it a second time. https://stackoverflow.com/a/12526509/18920732 This link should get you what you are looking for. Please take a look at the selected answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the issue is of course the browser land, and thus wanting to have code to clear the text box when you click on it?

You probably in most cases have to add some JavaScript, and then your be committed to making EVERY text box for a number on the site work that way to be consistent. It's not all that clear why you need/want a default value of 0, since what happens if the user clicks on that text box, and erases the 0?

Now you back to square one in which you wanting to avoid a text box without a value, and it now empty, right?

I think I would make the text box required, and also set the textmode = number.

That way, the user can't enter letters into the text box, and if they erase the 0, then they can't submit since you made the text box required.

And what is even worse then above? What do you want to occur when the user enters 0 into that text box?

Having stated all of the above?

Assuming jQuery, then this:

```
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtAmount" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"
            text="0"
            TextMode="Number">
        </asp:TextBox>


        <script>
            $('#txtAmount').on("focus", function (e) {
                if ($(this).val() == "0") {
                    $(this).val("")
                }
            })

        </script>
```

Comment: Hi! follow up question is what if the textbox is inside the table?