# Is it possible to focus a text box with a URL in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, url, firefox

Basically I have this addon called FoxReplace. It can replace words with other words, but I don't want it to do that on the an entire page, just one specific text box. The only means it provides of limiting its range is by using a URL, so I was wondering if there was a way to focus just a text box using a URL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you automatically set the focus to a textbox when a web page loads?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45827/how-do-you-automatically-set-the-focus-to-a-textbox-when-a-web-page-loads)

Comment: @Liam no, that's not a duplicate

Comment: and answer - you can't. even if you focus some element after page loading, page address will still be the same, and that plugin will either work on that page or not